# How do you convert axis tick values into scientific notation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, axes

I am trying to make the x axis of my plot in scientific notation, similar to how the y axis automatically formatted. Here is my code

```
start=float(t_array_hr[0])
stop=float(t_array_hr[-1])
xticks=(np.linspace(start,stop,8))

plt.plot(t_array_hr,Mdot_hr)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Mdot in Solar Masses/yr')
plt.title('Rate of Mass Loss vs Time')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.xticks(xticks,xticks)
plt.show()
```

Here is the resulting plot. (The actual graph does not show up but I will reserve that for a separate question.) I need the x ticks to be legible rather than overlapping.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass customized labels as the second argument to `xticks()`

```
plt.xticks(xticks,[f'{x:.2e}' for x in xticks])
```

Comment: better to use a locator + formatter instead of hard-coding like this.

Comment: "better" is subjective.  I think this way is easier to understand and directly modify, which is why I suggested it.  You are welcome to suggest a solution as well.

Comment: @coreyp_1 that worked to change each value into scientific notation, but I am still wondering if it is possible to format it as the y axis is, with the e^power shown at the end of the axis and only the first two digits shown at each tick mark?

Comment: @coreyp_1 correction: first 3 digits (2 decimal places)

Comment: @lauchter a simple slice can give you the first 4 characters of each string, but where are you intending to put the scientific notation indication?  What have you tried?

Comment: @coreyp_1 I intend to have the scientific notation indication at the right hand side of the x axis.I have tried set_scientific with no luck.